# How can I retrieve the phone number of a Windows Phone 8 device?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can I programmatically retrieve the phone number of a Windows Phone 8 device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not Possible. (for Security Reasons)